# Play a tone while key is down C#

Tags: c#, keypress, keydown, beep

I'm building a piano console application that plays a beep/tone with a specific frequency for a specific amount of time. Help
Eventually play the tone as long as the key is pressed.
P.S eventually play several tones at once

```
namespace something
{

 public class piano
 {

  [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
  static extern bool Beep(uint dwFreq, uint dwDuration);

  public static void  Main (string [] args)
    {

     Console.WriteLine("This is a piano.");

  //The following code is wrong but you get the idea
     char x = KeyDown;
     switch(x)

     case "q":
     Beep(523,500);
     break;

     case "w":
     Beep(587,500);
     break;

     //etc

     default:
     break;
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: What's your question exactly??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a console application you can detect when a key has been pressed, but not when it has been released. Therefore I would use a WinForms application.

In a WinForms Form you can use the `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` events at form level. In order to activate them, you must set the `KeyPreview` property of the form to `true`. You can do this in the properties window or in code.

Then you must remember which keys are pressed. I'm using a `HashSet<Keys>` for this.

```
// Stores the keys in pressed state.
private HashSet<Keys> _pressedKeys = new HashSet<Keys>();

// Used in DisplayKeys method.
private StringBuilder _sb = new StringBuilder();

// Form constructor
public frmKeyboard()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    KeyPreview = true; // Activate key preview at form level.
}

private void frmKeyboard_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Each time a key is pressed, add it to the set of pressed keys.
    _pressedKeys.Add(e.KeyCode);
    DisplayKeys();
}

private void frmKeyboard_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Each time a key is released, remove it from the set of pressed keys.
    _pressedKeys.Remove(e.KeyCode);
    DisplayKeys();
}

private void DisplayKeys()
{
    _sb.Clear();
    foreach (Keys key in _pressedKeys.OrderBy(k => k)) {
        _sb.AppendLine(key.ToString());
    }
    label1.Text = _sb.ToString();
}
```

Now, you can press one or more keys at a time and they will be displayed in a label.

---

The simple `Beep` method will not let you play sounds simultaneously. For a possible solution see this thread on MSDN: [Playing Sounds Simultaneously](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/63e8ec14-bd11-4a91-aaf0-87fc68ffc2b2/playing-sounds-simultaneously?forum=vbgeneral). Another alternative might be [MIDI.NET](http://midinet.codeplex.com/).